# Android setOnKeyListener not working when used in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-keypad

In the past I have been able to successfully set an onKeyListener that would detect if a user selected the return button on the android keyboard, this would then fire and action to send the user to another activity, however I now need to build this same functionality into a fragment, but when I use setOnKeyListener in the fragment it does not work for some reason, below I will post the code

My EditText

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/searchetedittext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/vineline_edittext_inner_background"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:hint="Search #Hashtags"
                android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete"
                android:lines="1"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColor="@color/button_color_dark"
                android:textSize="22dp" />
```

My setOnKeyListener

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View v;

    if (getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_SEARCH_TYPE) == 0) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_of_tab1, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.searchtrendlist);
        pb = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressbartab1);

        final LinearLayout searchButton = (LinearLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);

        final EditText searchEdittext = (EditText) v
                .findViewById(R.id.searchetedittext);
        searchEdittext.setTypeface(textStyleThin);

        searchEdittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {

                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        searchButton.performClick();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                postText = searchEdittext.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context,
                        HashtagScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("screenname", postText);
                startActivity(intent);

                searchEdittext.setText("");
            }
        });

        new setupTrends().execute();

    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_of_tab2, container, false);
        lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.searchfriendlist);
        pb = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressbartab2);

        final LinearLayout searchFriendButton = (LinearLayout) v
                .findViewById(R.id.searchfriendbutton);

        final EditText searchFriendEdittext = (EditText) v
                .findViewById(R.id.searchfriendedittext);
        searchFriendEdittext.setTypeface(textStyleThin);

        searchFriendEdittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    switch (keyCode) {

                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        searchFriendButton.performClick();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        searchFriendEdittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                    int before, int count) {

                try {
                    fdb.open();

                    if (s.toString().matches("")) {
                        friendListItems = fdb.getFriends();
                    } else {
                        friendListItems = fdb.sortFriends(s.toString());
                    }

                    userListsAdapter = new SearchFriendsAdapter(
                            getActivity(), friendListItems);

                    lv.setAdapter(userListsAdapter);

                    fdb.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                searchFriendEdittext.requestFocus();

            }
        });

        searchFriendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                postFriendText = searchFriendEdittext.getText().toString();

                if (postFriendText.length() > 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                            FriendProfileActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("screenname", postFriendText);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    searchFriendEdittext.setText("");
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Please enter a twitter username",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });

        fdb.open();

        friendListItems = fdb.getFriends();

        userListsAdapter = new SearchFriendsAdapter(getActivity(),
                friendListItems);

        lv.setAdapter(userListsAdapter);

        fdb.close();

        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    addHeader();

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us where do you set this listener? I mean in which callback

Comment: Its in the onCreateView of the fragment class

Comment: Did you checked if the onKey() method is being call? Maybe searchFriendButton.performClick() is the issue

Comment: Turns out onKey isnt being called at all, I will have to try to figure out why this doesnt happen in the fragment

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question but i got the answer when i set edittext's input type `android:inputType="textPersonName"`

Comment: This answer is ancient, but it helped me.  I was missing an inputType on my EditText view.  Trying to put an onKeyListener onto and EditText view within a dialog fragment.  Thankyou!   I added android:inputType="textCapSentences" and it worked immediately so it doesnt seem to matter what the input type is as long as you specify one.